# Divide data frame number equally in groups

Tags: r

I have a data frame with a column of names and more columns containing properties coded by 0 and 1 (equal to *no* and *yes*).

```
     Name     Running   Cycling
1     Adam     1         0
2     Steve    0         1
3     Aaron    1         1
4     Nick     1         0
5     Paul     1         0
6     Stuart   1         0
```

I now want to divide the *yes* equally into a given number of groups column-wise for all 1s and add the number of the related group in an additional column. If we would divide Running and Cycling in two groups each this should be the result:

```
Name     Running   Cycling  Running-Group Cycling-Group
1     Adam     1         0        1           0 
2     Steve    0         1        0           1
3     Aaron    1         1        1           2
4     Nick     1         0        1           0
5     Paul     1         0        2           0
6     Stuart   1         0        2           0
```

I can get the group number with:

```
ceiling(sum(column)/100*groups)
```

I am sure there is an easy way with R, however I couldn't find a solution which ignores the 0s (*nos*) and adds the group number only to the 1s (*yes*).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: In the expected result, I think there is a typo for `Running` column.. All the elements are 1.  Also, it is not clear how you got the expected result.  What is `groups` in the `ceiling` formula?

Comment: It is completely not clear. How do you obtain the two extra column on line 2 and 3 for examples?

Comment: I thought the description between the two tables would make it clear.... 
*1* should be interpreted as a *yes*, and I want to divide all yes in a defined number of groups. So if there are 8 *1s* and I want to create 4 groups, the first two Names with a *1* would be in group 1, the following two in group 2 and so on.

Comment: @Laura If you are dividing 1s equally, then the `0` in the first dataset for `Running` would be a typo. Otherwise, there would be odd number of `1s` i.e. 5 in number, and it is not clear how you divide the groups between the odd number.

Comment: I just can say sorry: that was indeed a typo and so it didn't make any sense. I edited it, hope that makes sense now.

Comment: @Laura I saw your edit, but why there is 3 `1`s and  2 `2s` for the Running group now.  Doesn't it break your initial description of equal division.

Comment: @akrun Since there is an odd number of people and 2 groups, it's not possible to divide them equally, so I have to round the middle person and have 3 people in group 1 and 2 in group 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this helps

```
nm1 <- paste(names(df1)[-1], 'Group', sep="_")
df1[nm1] <- lapply(df1[-1], function(x) {
                  x1 <- x==1
                  x[x1] <- gl(sum(x1),ceiling(sum(x1)/2), sum(x1))
                   x})
 df1
 #    Name Running Cycling Running_Group Cycling_Group
 #1   Adam       1       0             1             0
 #2  Steve       0       1             0             1
 #3  Aaron       1       1             1             2
 #4   Nick       1       0             1             0
 #5   Paul       1       0             2             0
 #6 Stuart       1       0             2             0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `grps` function shown below:

```
grp <- function(x) { 
  s <- seq_along(x)
  x * ((s > mean(s)) + 1)
}

grps <- function(x) ave(x, x, FUN = grp)

transform(DF, 
  Running_Group = grps(Running),
  Cycling_Group = grps(Cycling))
```

giving:

```
    Name Running Cycling Running_Group Cycling_Group
1   Adam       1       0             1             0
2  Steve       0       1             0             1
3  Aaron       1       1             1             2
4   Nick       1       0             1             0
5   Paul       1       0             2             0
6 Stuart       1       0             2             0
```

**Note:** We used the following as `DF`:

```
Lines <- "     Name     Running   Cycling
1     Adam     1         0
2     Steve    0         1
3     Aaron    1         1
4     Nick     1         0
5     Paul     1         0
6     Stuart   1         0"

DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```